# Infopath not saving repeating table data properly in xml file

Tags: 2010, infopath

We have an Infopath custom form published in a SharePoint library (as content type). This form has a repeating table with a few columns. The idea is, one department adds "issues" in the repeating table and the other department users mark those issue as "Resolved" etc once completed.

The repeating table data is not saved anywhere else (not promoted as a sharepoint field or even saved in another SP list) except in the actual XML files. This was working up until 10 days ago.

Now when department1's user submits these "issues" it sometimes saves them all, sometimes a few and other times none. By the time department2's user opens the form up, nothing is shown and even opening up the XML for the forms saved shows missing data. The form always opens up in browser so a clients installation for infopath is not used.

I have no idea where to even get a pinpoint for this issue. I have tried checking the network to see if its a network issue or IIS. Nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Example of the repeating table and missing data:
[image]

Comment: your InfoPath have code ?

Comment: No. Everything is achieved using inbuilt infopath features.

Comment: them have rules in submit form? or try set not null on field "Discrepancy". because that i see he is allowing "values null" for this field.

Comment: The only rules on submit are depending on a radio button the status of the form is changed (which determines which user the form should be redirected to) and then just "submit data using data connection". I will check if NULL is allowed or not in the discrepancy field. However, I have seen print screens of these forms before submission, all are filled out but after that things are missing.

Comment: "not null" is not set on the discrepancy field because its not ALWAYS a case that discrepancy is found. So cannot make it mandatory. I restarted the server for lack of anything better to do. Seems to have improved the situation. Still a few users still facing issues. made them use another PC and try submitting the same and these was no issue. Tried emptying their IE cache. No change. Still wondering what to do though.

Answer (score 0):

Check the XML files that have been submitted by opening them in a text editor to see if the data is actually missing.

If the data is in the XML files, have you had any updates to Internet Explorer recently? I have seen issues with data not being displayed in rich text fields in IE with Office 365, and adding the site to the compatibility view list caused the data to be displayed correctly again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I checked the XML files and there is no data saved. At first even I was thinking along the same lines that it might be a viewing issue. However it turns out that its not being saved in the first place.